# Can Firebase in-app messaging be used in iOS as an in-app feedback form feature?

Tags: ios, in-app, user-feedback, firebase-in-app-messaging

1. Is anyone currently using [Firebase in-app messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/) within their iOS app as a way to create end-user "open_start" feedback forms? If so, what are the current capabilities?
2. If basic feedback is possible, can we currently add an [in-app chat form like this one](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0)?

After researching best options for in-app feedback services, some suggested Parse, or Helpstack.io or InstaBug - I'd rather stick with Firebase because it's already installed, so please do not recommend those unless there is no other way.

Thanks,

VXP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Firebase In-App Messaging is an effective way for customizing messages and reaching out to users. It does not provide a communication channel for chatting with users.

I would recommend Instabug's in-app chat. Your users will reach you through a shake gesture (pop-up appearing upon shake found below) or other customizable gestures. You could then reach out to that user for whatever reason, e.g., asking for more feedback or letting them know their issue's been fixed.

You could get notified on Firebase instantly by integrating Instabug with Zapier if you would like to streamline your workflow on Firebase.

Here's their [in-app chat](https://instabug.com/in-app-chat) page. It's pretty easy to integrate the SDK, takes a line of code.

[image: Instabug shake to send feedback]

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if there is anything I can do for you.

Comment: Which Insta-bug pricing tier will I need to pay to get that in-app chat feature? 

Instabug pricing - https://instabug.com/pricing

Comment: It goes under the silver plan which costs $249 monthly. It also includes, in-app-surveys, feature requests, app analytics, and full 3rd party integrations.